# Volatile vs Atomic in Java, why do we need atomic toolkit

Tags: java, multithreading

Volatile eliminates visibility and ordering issues. While [atomic toolkit](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) provides atomicity of operations. 
Volatile uses [happens-before](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happened-before) relation and Atomic uses compare and swap.

Why there is a need to introduce new layer of abstraction like atomic toolkit, instead of enhancing volatile keyword itself? Is there any specific cases which may be solved by atomic toolkit?

Comment: Atomic is NOT a keyword.

Answer (score 2):

Actually if you'll take closer look into [`Atomic*`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) [implemetations](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.java#62) then you'll see that all of them holds `volatile` field with value.

IMHO atomics is already an extension of volatile mechanism which provides convenient way to do atomic `CAS` operations.

Also there is a benefits of hiding `CAS` implementation. For example hotspot jvm heavily uses intrinsics to achieve to squeeze performance.

Answer (score 0):

Changing an existing language construct like `volatile` would most likely mean that you break existing applications. So this is typically not an option, in particular not for the Java language. Creating a new library does not effect existing applications and is thus completely backwards compatible.

In addition to that, the classes in the `atomic`package offer advanced operations like `compareAndSet` that you cannot just add to the `volatile` keyword.